# Caption not working while subcaptions are present

Tags: captions, subcaption

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \subcaption{Lorem1}
  \label{asd:a}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \subcaption{Lorem2}
  \label{asd:b}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \subcaption{Lorem3}
  \label{asd:c}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \caption{ASD}
  \label{asd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And I get the following output:

[image]

The code delivers an output with 'ASD' subcaption.
However, I want to get it as a caption in form `Figure xx`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the [package documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) (p. 4) reveals:

> Please note that the \subcaption command must be applied inside its
>   own box or environment.

Thus, following the example from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \subcaption{Lorem1}
  \label{asd:a}
  \end{minipage}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \subcaption{Lorem2}
  \label{asd:b}
  \end{minipage}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \subcaption{Lorem3}
  \label{asd:c}
  \end{minipage}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \caption{ASD}
  \label{asd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively use the `subfigure` environment provided:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \caption{Lorem1}
  \label{asd:a}
  \end{subfigure}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \caption{Lorem2}
  \label{asd:b}
  \end{subfigure}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{image1}
  \caption{Lorem3}
  \label{asd:c}
  \end{subfigure}\par\vspace{5mm}
  \caption{ASD}
  \label{asd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair should do also (untested, however!)